# Does jquery or javascript execute when loaded dynamically on an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I have a dropdown and when i choose an option it will load an appropriate table from the server and display it using jQuery, along with the table i also send a tiny jQuery script like,

```
        <table id="dataFileTableHeader">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Export Type</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Company</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>File Name</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Date Modified</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Total Records</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>File Size</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Owner</strong></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <script>
        $(function(){
            var i = 0;
            $('#dataFileTableHeader th').each(function(index) {
                alert("hello " + (++i));
            });
        });
        </script>
```

when this is loaded i am expecting `alert` to show up 7 times but nothing happens am i missing something?

Comment: The most important code is the one that loads the table. Usually, whenever AJAX is involved there are callback functions or a way to ask that script is the result get executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/3b835/1)

You have a space after your id

(`<table id="dataFileTableHeader ">` instead of `<table id="dataFileTableHeader">`

So this one is correct

```
    <table id="dataFileTableHeader">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Export Type</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Company</strong></th>
                <th><strong>File Name</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Date Modified</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Total Records</strong></th>
                <th><strong>File Size</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Owner</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var i = 0;
        $('#dataFileTableHeader th').each(function(index) {
            alert("hello " + (++i));
        });
    });
    </script>
```

You can also just use the index in the alert to grab the number. You don't need "i"

Comment: yep. you beat me to it ;). You can also just use the index in the alert to grab the number. You don't need "i".

Comment: the space was a mistake when copy/pasting and changing the id i have a different id on my application but it doesn't work for this dynamically loaded content

Comment: @Kathy: as you can see, it works pretty fine even for ajax loaded content: [try it out](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/c9c61)

Answer (score 1):

If your content is dynamically loaded, the script is probably being run before the content gets there. Have this code after your "success" parameters in your ajax function (hard to say without seeing that code). Make sense?

Comment: Thank you Julie i could go for this option but i don't want to have this code on the client side unless otherwise needed to i am making sure most of the javascript code is on the serverside but fetched only when needed